# Why does indenting if-else with tabs break a Makefile?

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu-make

Here's a Makefile:

```
.PHONY: all

ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
    DETECTED_OS := Windows

else
    DETECTED_OS := $(shell uname -s)

endif

$(info DETECTED_OS is set to '$(DETECTED_OS)')
```

When indented with tabs it prints

`DETECTED_OS is set to ''`

But when indented with 0 or more spaces it prints

`DETECTED_OS is set to 'Linux'`

But if you delete the first line `.PHONY: all` it prints

`DETECTED_OS is set to 'Linux'`

regardless of tabs or spaces.

So the first version is broken because it sets `DETECTED_OS` to nothing. Why is that?

My make version:

```
GNU Make 4.1
Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 1988-2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you indent a line with a TAB, make assumes it's part of a recipe for the previous target if there is one.  In this case, there's the `.PHONY` target, so make is assuming that these two lines are part of the recipe for the `.PHONY` target (which is never used).  Because of that, these make variable assignments are not run.

The simple rule for makefiles is, always indent recipe lines with TAB, and never indent any other lines with TAB.

Comment: Just to add to @MadScientist's excellent answer, once these tab indented lines become part of a recipe, if run, they would be interpreted by shell and not by make.